# Найти все цепочки последовательных отрезков из графика/таблицы

Tags: python, динамическое-программирование, числовые-последовательности

У меня есть таблица с отрезками (около 11к отрезков), у каждого отрезка определены начальная и конечная координата, эти отрезки находятся внутри географического полигона.[таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RfK5F3yVuiUiNEaC3P8FK-RxlOHv_gN9/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=105326785031219603112&rtpof=true&sd=true)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно составить цепочки из последовательных отрезков или объединить их в единую сеть без замкнутых полигонов. последовательные отрезки = отрезки соединяются в начале или конце.

что я попробовал в силу своих начальных знаний python:

Имеющиеся координаты X1 (6 цифр), Y1 (7 цифр), X2 (6 цифр), Y2 (7 цифр) переделал в тип str, перевел в tolist и получил лист из 26-значных цифр.

Пытался пойти по пути [названий стран](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.3c190020-645b7a86-99ef19f4-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/10548712/longest-chain-of-elements-from-list-in-python) и переписал код, чтобы пересечение со следующим отрезком происходило по 13 последним числам.

```
acc_V_in_R = pd.read_excel('try.xlsx')
poi1 = acc_V_in_R[['X_x', 'Y_x']]
poi1 = poi1['X_x'].astype ( str ) + poi1['Y_x'].astype ( str )
poi2 = acc_V_in_R[['X_y', 'Y_y']]
poi2 = poi2['X_y'].astype ( str ) + poi2['Y_y'].astype ( str )
poi1_poi2 = poi1 + poi2
poi1_poi2 = poi1_poi2.tolist()

def cha(point, poi1_poi2):
    remaining = list(poi1_poi2)
    del remaining[remaining.index(point)]
    possibles = [x for x in remaining if x[:13] == point[-13:]]
    maxchain = []
    for c in possibles:
        l = cha(c, remaining)
        if len(l) > len(maxchain):
            maxchain = l
    return [point] + maxchain
 print(cha('31750247849113176614783977', poi1_poi2))
```

в результате получается почти бесконечный код из непонятного текста и
Restarting kernel...

даже по одному из отрезков для примера '31750247849113176614783977' никакой последовательности отрезков построить не получается.

Хотелось было получить все возможные цепочки из отрезков.

Comment: Почитайте что такое граф и как по графу построить остовное дерево (например обходом в глубину).